# SQLiteNet Index and Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sqlite, lambda, xamarin

We are using Xamarin with SQLiteNet as ORM.

In our data layer class we have the method below.

```
filter = ri => ri.ItemVersioniId == itemVersionId;
```

The method is getting the records matching the Id. If the lambda expression is hardcoded, instead of using the "filter" parameter it is much faster... even though it is the same logic.

We would to be able to pass the filter as a parameter but still get a good performance. Any advise?

```
public virtual List<ResourceItem> GetResourceItems (string itemVersionId, Func<ResourceItem,bool> filter ){

        //var t = db.Table<ResourceItem> ().Where (ri => ri.ItemVersionId == itemVersionId); --* this line is 10 times faster

        var t = db.Table<ResourceItem> ().Where (filter); --* this line is 10 times slower

        return new List<ResourceItem> (t);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure because it is `xamarin` specific, but i suggest to use `Expression` instead of `Func`.

```
Expression<Func<ResourceItem,bool>> filter =
              ri => ri.ItemVersioniId == itemVersionId; 

public virtual List<ResourceItem> GetResourceItems
         (string itemVersionId, Expression<Func<ResourceItem,bool>> filter )
{
    return db.Table<ResourceItem> ().Where (filter).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The SQLite-Net function signature for `Where` is already an expression: `(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predExpr)`.. so it already must be..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead But caller method signature requires parameter of type `Func<ResourceItem,bool>`.

Comment: This was it. I am not familiar with the 'expressions'... I guess I have to make my homework and find out how they are different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise hard coding it. Here is why, but first let me qualify this by saying I am speculating - I have no experience with SQLiteNet - this based on some general, rudimentary knowledge on how LINQ Prodivers work.

When you have it hard coded the lambda expression is converted to SQL at compile time. When you set it to a delegate, it could be a LINQ to Objects query, there is no way to know at compile time that your LINQ Provider can convert that to a SQL statement. Instead this work occurs at runtime and as a result the performance suffers greatly.